# What could be causing my Thermostat "R" wire to only be 8 VAC?

Tags: hvac, furnace, thermostat, nest

I am trying to install a Nest thermostat.

It says Rh not powered. I checked with a meter and I get approx **8 VAC** reading.

What could be causing this?

[image: Nest Error]

The furnace itself ain't pretty.

[image: Furnace clusterf@@@@]

Update:

[image: 01]

[image: 02]

[image: 03]

Comment: 1) What did you use for neutral/return when measuring the voltage?  2) What is the voltage on that line right at the furnace?

Comment: The wiring for the thermostat is in the bottom  portion of the furnace (just about where your photo ends).

Comment: Can you get us a better photo of the wiring?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I opened a light switch and used ground, but also checked between Rh and C. I can confirm when I get home.

Comment: I will get a better photo after work. And can check voltages again, too

Comment: Added more photos

Comment: Can you get us clear close-ups of both the fan compartment wiring and the bundle on the left side of the burner compartment?  You sure have a rat's nest in there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a furnace guy come in the morning. He saw the furnace and said "Oh my god!"

After two hours he decided he couldn't figure it out and they sent another guy later that day.

They finally figured it out.

Since a guy who works with furnaces for a living couldn't figure it out after two hours I think I never had a chance to begin with.

So in the end, the answer was:

Call a pro.

Comment: Yeah -- what did the pros find, btw? I'm curious...